# Method to integrate M Code (DML) of one Power Query into another?

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have multiple PowerQuery codes I've developed. Now, I'm ready to place them into text files and/or use VBA to transfer them between Excel workbooks. I'd like to try to collapse all the parts I can into eachother, to simplify these transfers.

Is there a way to methodically integrate the M Code from one PowerQuery query into the M Code of another PowerQuery query?

Query 1: "MainPowerQueryQuery"

```
let
Source = Table.NestedJoin(#"dqyDirLevel3-Excel-PathsAndKeys",{"KeyField"},#"AnotherPowerQueryQuery",{"KeyField"},"AnotherPowerQueryQuery",JoinKind.Inner),
#"Expanded Column of Tables of Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Source, "AnotherPowerQueryQuery", {"Index", "SEQUENCE", "ID", "UNIT", "SYSTEM", "INSTANCE", "SYSTEM-COUNT", "SHORT", "LS", "AS", "RS", "S_", "AE", "STATUS", "AN"}, {"Index", "SEQUENCE", "ID", "UNIT", "SYSTEM", "INSTANCE", "SYSTEM-COUNT", "SHORT", "LS", "AS", "RS", "S_", "AE", "STATUS", "AN"})
in
#"Expanded Column of Tables of Data"
```

Query 2: "AnotherPowerQueryQuery"

```
let
Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("\\share\path\to\my\other\Workbook.xlsx"), null, true){[Item="tblPX",Kind="Table"]}[Data] 
in
Source
```

I'm looking to make a Query  3 that consists of the code of Query 2 inside of a copy of Query 1, such that I could delete both Queries 1 and 2, and keep just Query 3.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "integrate", but you can just copy and paste queries from one file to another (not just the M code, the entire query).

Comment: I'm trying to combine the actual code of two distinct PowerQueries into one combined code -- to simplify moving them around.

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: @Olly: Added example codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the steps in one query:

```
let
    LookupTable = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("\\share\path\to\my\other\Workbook.xlsx"), null, true){[Item="tblPX",Kind="Table"]}[Data], 
    Source = Table.NestedJoin(#"dqyDirLevel3-Excel-PathsAndKeys",{"KeyField"},LookupTable,{"KeyField"},"LookupTable",JoinKind.Inner),
    #"Expanded Column of Tables of Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Source, "LookupTable", {"Index", "SEQUENCE", "ID", "UNIT", "SYSTEM", "INSTANCE", "SYSTEM-COUNT", "SHORT", "LS", "AS", "RS", "S_", "AE", "STATUS", "AN"}, {"Index", "SEQUENCE", "ID", "UNIT", "SYSTEM", "INSTANCE", "SYSTEM-COUNT", "SHORT", "LS", "AS", "RS", "S_", "AE", "STATUS", "AN"})
in
    #"Expanded Column of Tables of Data"
```

Comment: Didn't work for me... I just get "Expression.SyntaxError: Token Comma expected."
Trying to add a comma to the end of Line 2 (line after let command) didn't work for me either. 

Do I need multiple let commands somehow?

Comment: Actually, it just worked with that comma added to the end of the line beginning with LookupTable. THANK YOU!

Comment: Oh yes. I missed a comma. You found it. ;-)